# Is it not possible to use `in psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I want to upload data to postgresql using psycopg2.

The commands to use other extensions that I use are as follows.

```
\set content `cat file path`
INSERT INTO tablename (column) VALUES (:'content');
```

Additionally, in psycopg2, \set was not available, so I changed it to SET.

However, there was one more problem with psycopg2.

`(backtick) is not recognized.

The error appears as

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "`".
```

Are there any other methods I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get anywhere that way, since all these commands and features are specific to the command line client `psql`.

Comment: The other commands didn't have a problem, just because of the backtick? Or is it impossible to set a variable?

Comment: There is no variable in SQL. `SET` changes a database parameter. Use Python variables and a prepared statement.